# Image popup on hover in DT in R

Tags: css, r, datatables, r-markdown, dt

I  have a `DT` within a `Rmarkdown` and I would like an image to pop up when hovering over table data.

What i have so for seems to work but it distorts the `datatable`.

It increases the table rows height to fit the image. I have tried to reduce the row sizes via `css` but with no luck.

This is the `Rmarkdown` I have so far:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "dimitris_ps"
date: "3 September 2016"
output: html_document
---

<style type="text/css"> 

  .imgTooltip {
      visibility: hidden;
}

  .ItemsTooltip:hover .imgTooltip {
      visibility: visible;
}

  td {
      height: 14px;
}

</style>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(DT)

df <- structure(list(a = c("<a class=\"ItemsTooltip\" href=\"http://www.example.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img class=\"imgTooltip\" src=\"https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSSEu.jpg\"/>my stackoverflow Avatar</a>", 
"<a class=\"ItemsTooltip\" href=\"http://www.example.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img class=\"imgTooltip\" src=\"https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSSEu.jpg\"/>my stackoverflow Avatar</a>"
), b = c("<a class=\"ItemsTooltip\" href=\"http://www.example.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img class=\"imgTooltip\" src=\"https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSSEu.jpg\"/>my stackoverflow Avatar</a>", 
"<a class=\"ItemsTooltip\" href=\"http://www.example.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img class=\"imgTooltip\" src=\"https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSSEu.jpg\"/>my stackoverflow Avatar</a>"
)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

```{r}
datatable(df, escape=c(FALSE, FALSE))
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your CSS to use `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden` like so:

```
  .imgTooltip {
      display: none;
}

  .ItemsTooltip:hover .imgTooltip {
      display: block;
}
```

If I were doing this I would probably use the `datatable` callback option instead of rendering the images in the cells, but I'd have to think about it some more.

edit: Here is a cleaner version using `columnDefs`

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "CG"
date: "6 September 2016"
output: 
  html_document:
    md_extensions: +raw_html
---

<style type="text/css"> 

.imgTooltip {
      display: none;
}

.ItemsTooltip:hover .imgTooltip {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
}

</style>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 a = rep("my stackoverflow Avatar",2),
                 b = rep("my stackoverflow Avatar",2))

```

```{r}
datatable(df, options=list(columnDefs=list(list(
  targets=1:2,render=DT::JS(
    'function(data,row,type,meta) {
      return "<a class=\'ItemsTooltip\' href=\'www.example.com\' target=\'_blank\'><img class=\'imgTooltip\' src=\'https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSSEu.jpg\'/>" +
      data + "</a>";
    }'
    )
  ))))
```
````

Comment: Great this is what i was looking for. Thnx

Comment: what if we want to show a different image on each row, reading the url from a column of the data.frame?