# CSS tooltip on DataTables

Tags: javascript, css, r, datatables, dt

I am trying to create some tooltip on a datatable that I build with R. I am very new to this and merely tried to adapt the solution proposed on this post [Image popup on hover in DT in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309111/image-popup-on-hover-in-dt-in-r) to my situation, but it only provides the possibility to add a hyperlink (below "page_to_replace") or a image tooltip ("image_to_replace") to a whole column. 
I would like to have a dedicated tooltip for each value of the column, can I do this playing with the CSS config or the JS function I defined ?

Thanks for your help, below the code I use so far

```html
--- in Markdown file
<style type="text/css"> 

  .imgTooltip {
      visibility: hidden;
}

  .ItemsTooltip:hover .imgTooltip {
      visibility: visible;
}

  td {
      height: 14px;
}

</style>

--- in R script

    JScommand <- 'function(data,row,type,meta) {
      return "<a class=\'ItemsTooltip\' href=\'page_to_replace\' target=\'_blank\'><img class=\'imgTooltip\' src=\'image_to_replace\'/>" +
      data + "</a>";
      }'

    dt <- DT::datatable(data2,
              options = list(autoWidth = TRUE,
                             columnDefs = list(list(width = '90px', targets = c(0:6)),
                                               list(className = 'dt-right', targets = c(0:6)),
                                               list(targets = 4, render=DT::JS(JScommand))
                                               ),
                            )
                        )
```